# Benefits of using functional endpoints instead of @Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

With functional endpoints, I have to do:

```
route(GET("/..."), req -> ok().body(myService.method(...))
```

or

```
route(GET("/..."), myHandler::myGetMethod)
```

What's the point? It seems like there will be the same amount of objects and methods (lambda or handler method instead of controller method), same number of urls, etc. Extracting request parameters and building response (status, body etc), is much more verbose and (subjectively) less readable.

I'm aware that annotations are not composable, and in general, it's easier to work with normal code rather than with annotations. However, in this specific case, I don't see any benefits. Nonetheless, there is a lot of hype related to it. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you post a link to some of the hype? I'd be interested to have a read.